# NSInternalInconsistencyException in coreData Fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to show customer name in the section header and his transactions in the rows.
I used coredata and NSFetched Results Controller to achieve this.But am getting an NSInternalconsistencyException.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
NSLog(@"number of sections %lu",[_fetchedResultsController sections].count);
return [[_fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
XXPerson *customer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]];
NSLog(@"number of rows %lu",(unsigned long)[customer.transaction count]);
return [customer.transaction count];
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  NSIndexPath *adjustedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath section] inSection:0];
  NSLog(@"Section: %ld, Row: %ld", (long)adjustedIndexPath.section, (long)adjustedIndexPath.row);
  Customer *person = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:adjustedIndexPath];
  NSSet *unsortedTransactions = [person transaction];
  NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"monthNumber" ascending:YES];
  self.transactions = [unsortedTransactions sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sort, nil]];
  Transaction *transaction = [self.transactions objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
  NSString *amountDepositedStr = [transaction valueForKey:@"amountDeposited"];
  cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", amountDepositedStr];
  NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", amountDepositedStr]);
}
```

And the log is :

```
2014-04-25 12:23:04.277 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of sections 6
2014-04-25 12:23:04.286 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of sections 6
2014-04-25 12:23:04.288 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of rows 3
2014-04-25 12:23:04.288 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of rows 3
2014-04-25 12:23:04.289 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of rows 3
2014-04-25 12:23:04.289 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of rows 3
2014-04-25 12:23:04.290 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of rows 3
2014-04-25 12:23:04.290 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] number of rows 3
2014-04-25 12:23:04.292 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] Section: 0, Row: 0
2014-04-25 12:23:04.293 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] 20
2014-04-25 12:23:04.294 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] Section: 0, Row: 0
2014-04-25 12:23:04.295 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] 10
2014-04-25 12:23:04.296 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] Section: 0, Row: 0
2014-04-25 12:23:04.296 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] 110
2014-04-25 12:23:04.297 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] Section: 0, Row: 1
2014-04-25 12:23:04.298 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] 40
2014-04-25 12:23:04.299 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] Section: 0, Row: 1
2014-04-25 12:23:04.299 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] 30
2014-04-25 12:23:04.300 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] Section: 0, Row: 1
2014-04-25 12:23:04.300 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] 310
2014-04-25 12:23:04.301 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] Section: 0, Row: 2
2014-04-25 12:23:04.304 CoreDataExample[2179:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 2 in section at index 0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101cbd495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101a1c99e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreData                            0x000000010035dc08 -[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:] + 408
3   CoreDataExample                     0x0000000100003617 -[XXCustomerTableViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] + 279
4   CoreDataExample                     0x0000000100003a5e -[XXCustomerTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 142
5   UIKit                               0x000000010069df8a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 348
6   UIKit                               0x0000000100683d5b -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2337
7   UIKit                               0x0000000100695721 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
8   UIKit                               0x0000000100629993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
9   QuartzCore                          0x00000001049df802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
10  QuartzCore                          0x00000001049d4369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
11  QuartzCore                          0x00000001049d41ea _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104947fb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104949030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
14  UIKit                               0x00000001005c8024 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 10914
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c4cd21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c4c5f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c6846f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c67d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ceef04 GSEventRunModal + 161
20  UIKit                               0x00000001005c9e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
21  CoreDataExample                     0x0000000100007553 main + 115
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001023555fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What does your - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method look like?  The first thing that stands out is that you're modifying the index path, so you might be trying to access an out of bounds row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `configureCell:` to

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     NSIndexPath *adjustedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:[indexPath section]];
     ....
}
```